# Can WCF be hosted on Windows Nano Server 2016?

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, nano-server

I am fairly sure Windows Nano Server 2016 only supports .net core, but I wanted to be sure...

Is there any way to run a WCF service on Windows Nano Server 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, to make nano server lean there are only few packages/features supported (DNS,IIS,FailoverCluster..). The full .net framework isn't supported on Nano server and hence any service dependent on this (including WCF) wont be supported. Apart from asp.net core, PHP and JAVA will still work great on Nano.

Comment: I find it depressing that a "competing" framework (Java) is supported, but not Microsoft's own .NET Framework.  But you are correct.